# How to modify MODIS subset function to download product for a specific region and time period?

Tags: raster, r, remote-sensing, modis

I am trying to assess the land cover change that has occurred over East Asia over last 18 years only in winters (Oct-Jan) for which I want to use MOD13Q1 dataset of modis from 2000-2018. I am using the mt_subset function to download the data.

I have already downloaded a sample data from Netherlands but I am unable to understand how to fetch my required dataset through this function which should have all the products from Oct-Jan (2000-2018) and the layer should be 250m NDVI. This website provides information about the library for downloading product `https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MODISTools/vignettes/modistools-vignette.html`

Here is how i am currently downloading the data.

```
VI <- mt_subset(product = "MOD13Q1",
                site_id = "nl_gelderland_loobos",
                band = "250m_16_days_NDVI",
                start = "2000-01-01",
                km_lr = 2,
                km_ab = 2,
                site_name = "testsite",
                internal = TRUE,
                progress = TRUE)
```

The location should ideally be as shown in the image (East China) and the start and end dates should only be for winters so that it only downloads products for that specific area and dates. How should I modify the arguments of this function to accomplish this task?[image]

Answer (score -2):

MODIS data since 2013 is available on [landviewer](https://eos.com/landviewer). You can set the time period needed and download the data for personal use anytime or analyse the images on spot via built-in tools.

[image]

MODIS 2000 - 2013 data isn't available but you may get it from other satellites whose imagery is also accessible.

Here's the full list:

- MODIS - archive since 2012
- Sentinel-1 - archive since 2014
- Sentinel-2 - archive since 2015
- Landsat 4 - archive 1982-1993
- Landsat 5 - archive 1984-2013
- Landsat 7 - archive since 1999
- Landsat 8 - archive since 2013